# ETL from SQL Server with AWS Glue in Python

Tags: python, pyodbc, aws-glue

I need to write an ETL job that run regularly with AWS Glue, in Python. The job is to query data SQL Server. If I do this on local machine, I need to install `pyodbc` (`pip install pyodbc` and an ODBC driver (from [here](https://developers.snowflake.com/odbc/)), and run this sample Python code (referenced from [here](https://hevodata.com/learn/python-sql-server-integration/)):

```
cnxn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
            "Server=USXXX00345,67800;"
            "Database=DB02;"
            "UID=Alex;"
            "PWD=Alex123;")
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
```

If I want to do this in an AWS Glue job, how do  I install the ODBC driver and  `pyodbc` in order to `import pyodbc`

Answer (score 1):

pyodbc is available by default in aws glue python shell jobs. Please keep track of the official aws docs to know the latest running version. You may also find a list of other supported and managed libraries in below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html

You could go ahead and import pyodbc.

Comment: This only partially answers the question. I think you still need to install the database driver. I'm not yet sure how to do that.

Comment: Hey I came across a work around for SQL server connection from Glue Python shell jobs. Please refer the original solution in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75106654/20642504 Even though, Glue now contains pyodbc module in-situ it doesnt show us how we can use a custom driver. pymssql module allows us to import the sql server driver by importing whl file that packs the sql server driver within it. Glue connection would still be reqd.